# Concatenate two XML nodes using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I've been trying to concatenate two XML elements into one.

Input File

```
<Location>
        <Location_Name>Test Location</Location_Name>
        <Address>
            <Country>USA</Country>
            <Address_Line_Data>2 Sample St</Address_Line_Data>
            <Address_Line_Data>35 Wentworth Ave</Address_Line_Data>
            <Municipality>Meier</Municipality>
        </Address>
</Location>
```

Desired Output file

```
<Location>
        <Location_Name>Test Location</Location_Name>
        <Address>
            <Country>USA</Country>
            <Address_Line_Data>2 Sample St - 35 Wentworth Ave</locc:Address_Line_Data>
            <Municipality>Meier</Municipality>
        </Address>
</Location>
```

How can I achieve that using XSLT ?

I've tried the following but no success.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Location/Address/Address_line_Data"">
    <xsl:for-each select=".">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,' - ')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: `<Address_Line_Data>2 Sample St</locc:Address_Line_Data>` is not even well-formed, neither in the input nor in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
  <xsl:template match="Address_Line_Data[1]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="../Address_Line_Data" separator=" - "/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Address_Line_Data[position() gt 1]"/>
```

plus the identity transformation template you have.

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Martin Honnen. That's exactly what I was looking for. Just for cosmetic sake, I've also added the tag ` <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` which removes the blank line left by the concatenation. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you could do this.
Make sure your input XML is well-formed, there's a "locc:" that shouldn't be there.
Also when you refer to an element or attribute, you need to use the exact name, as it is in the input.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Address_Line_Data[position()=1]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="../Address_Line_Data" separator=" - "/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Address_Line_Data[position()!=1]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93nwMnV

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sebastien. That's exactly what I was looking for. 
Just for cosmetic sake, I've also added the tag `   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` which removes the blank line left by the concatenation.

Cheers